# What is The Meaning of "Single digit body"?

Tags: book-title

I am reading a book: "A Man Called Ove". in the first chapter I face with this sentence:"The assistant, a young man with a single-digit body mass index, looks ill at ease." would you please explain what's the meaning of this?

best regard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be a BMI of max. 9 (one digit); it has to be less than 10 (two digits).

"Single-digit" refers to the entire term "body mass index" (BMI).

Comment: Yes, presumably an example of hyperbole. If the assistant was 1.78m (5ft10ins) tall he would have to  weigh less than 30kg (66lbs) to have a BMI of less than 10. This would bring him close to death's door.